# Matplotlib python create multiple bar graphs simultaneously

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following python (matplotlib) code below that generates a set of horizontal bar graphs each (length and location) independent of each other.

Execution takes about 12 seconds.

Is there some way for me to create one whole bar at a time or create multiple bars simultaneously? Or speed this up in any way? The calls to the plt.barh are the ones that take up almost all of the time.

Thanks.

```
import random,matplotlib.pyplot as plt,traceback,sys
names=['Asia','America','Africa','Australia']
list_empty_subsystems=[0 for i in range(len(names))]
x=range(len(names))

def add_barh(name, duration, _offset, label):

    global list_empty_subsystems
    try:

        bar_width=1

        time_offset_array=list_empty_subsystems[:]
        duration_list=list_empty_subsystems[:]
        time_offset_array[names.index(name)]=_offset
        duration_list[names.index(name)]=duration

        color='#'+str(hex(random.randint(0x100000,0xFFFFFE))[2:])
        #print color

        plt.barh(bottom=x, width=duration_list, height=bar_width,
                 color=color, alpha=1, left=time_offset_array,
                 edgecolor='#010101',linewidth=0.25)

    except Exception as e:
        print 'graph error',type(e),e,traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[-1], 1)[0],color

if __name__ == '__main__':


    time_=time.clock()
    for i in range(1000):
        index=random.randint(0,len(names)-1)

        add_barh(names[index],random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,10),names[index])
    plt.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
    print time.clock()-time_

    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

[image]

I found some solution in using patches.rectangle instead of barh for the same purpose, with ~50x speed.

Comment: I figured combining non overlapping values for one set of graphs at a time is a first step, (eg plot the first set of 4 graphs, then the next set)

Comment: It's not at all surprising that plotting 1000 bar plots takes a lot of time. If you really want to show 1000 bars on your plot, using meshed plots like `pcolormesh` would be much faster. However, since 95% of your bars are not even shown in the figure, it would be better to limit the amount of bars to plot previous to plotting.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is there some way to scale pcolormesh for lengths, like my barh plot?

Comment: Scaling itself is not a problem. It's more that pcolormesh would need a common scale for all categories, i.e. what is the end of one "bar" needs to be an end for pixels on the other categories as well; so it would be necessary to convert the data to a matrix on a grid first.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, try modeling your horizontal bar graph after this [stacked (vertical) bar graph](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) example (if you haven't seen it already). The [pyplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html) for bar() and barh() are very similar, so getting this all to work for a horizontal graph should not be an issue.

**Secondly**, let's talk about what you're trying to plot in your graph:

--

When charts like this one are made, it is normal to:

1. Have bar segments (colors) in common across the different groups (Australia, Africa, America, Asia), AND
2. Have FEWER than 20-40 different types of bar segments (colors)

Why?

- Having **bar segments in common** will **reduce the time** it takes to render this chart because we can render multiple bar segments at once (in this case, we would only have to run barh() once for each industry).
- Having **fewer than 20-40** different types of bar segments will also **reduce the render time** because running the bar() function 40x is really not that bad.

For example, if we were to make a horizontal bar chart that displayed the breakdown of GDP of each of your four areas by industry (Real Estate, Healthcare, Agriculture, etc.), then we would have ~20 bar segments in common across all of the groups. Overall, this means that we're only running the barh() function **20x** (compared to your example, in which you're running the function **1000x**).

That's a big difference, and I'm sure you'll see a fairly noticeable difference in run times.

Comment: I did the combine thing using https://stackoverflow.com/q/45359241/5252492. Additionally, if you look at your example, the person calls bar multiple times, which is my issue, even with the reduction, I'm still calling bar like 200+ times, which is a massive time to render.

Comment: Got it. I misunderstood your question.What's the overall purpose of your chart? Is it to generate those random bars? Or is the set of random bars just your example?

Comment: the random bars are my example. I have images that are generated from an unpredictable source, hence random

Comment: And what are you doing with the images that are generated? In cases like this, it's tricky to come up with a solution if you don't know what purpose of the chart is.